# json_decode fails to decode json data

Tags: php, json

In GitLab web hooks this is the json they give as an example.

```
{
  "before": "95790bf891e76fee5e1747ab589903a6a1f80f22",
  "after": "da1560886d4f094c3e6c9ef40349f7d38b5d27d7",
  "ref": "refs/heads/master",
  "user_id": 4,
  "user_name": "John Smith",
  "project_id": 15,
  "repository": {
    "name": "Diaspora",
    "url": "git@localhost:diaspora.git",
    "description": "",
    "homepage": "http://localhost/diaspora",
  },
  "commits": [
    {
      "id": "b6568db1bc1dcd7f8b4d5a946b0b91f9dacd7327",
      "message": "Update Catalan translation to e38cb41.",
      "timestamp": "2011-12-12T14:27:31+02:00",
      "url": "http://localhost/diaspora/commits/b6568db1bc1dcd7f8b4d5a946b0b91f9dacd7327",
      "author": {
        "name": "Jordi Mallach",
        "email": "jordi@softcatala.org",
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "da1560886d4f094c3e6c9ef40349f7d38b5d27d7",
      "message": "fixed readme",
      "timestamp": "2012-01-03T23:36:29+02:00",
      "url": "http://localhost/diaspora/commits/da1560886d4f094c3e6c9ef40349f7d38b5d27d7",
      "author": {
        "name": "Code Solution dev user",
        "email": "gitlabdev@dv6700.(none)",
      },
    },
  ],
  "total_commits_count": 4,
}
```

I've placed this in a file `test.json`.

I'm calling this with file_get_contents() then trying to decode but I'm getting nothing back at all.

```
$test = file_get_contents('test.json');

$json = json_decode($test); 

echo "<pre>";
print_r($json);
echo "</pre>";
```

returns:

```
<pre></pre>
```

Any ideas why `json_decode()` is failing to decode?

Comment: The following two functions should tell you: http://php.net/json_last_error and http://php.net/json_last_error_msg - https://eval.in/132156 - It says "Syntax error". Most likely this is no json at all. Jup: There is no comma after the last value of an object, see http://json.org/ - So the string you've got ain't no JSON.

Comment: your JSON is invalid, too many extra commas... fix the json

Answer (score 2):

It is because of a stray comma. You should check for errors:

```
if (json_last_error() != JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
    die(json_last_error_msg());
}
```

If you have PHP <5.5.0 then you can use [this compatibility function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php#113243):

```
if ( ! function_exists('json_last_error_msg')) {
    function json_last_error_msg() {
        static $errors = array(
            JSON_ERROR_NONE             => null,
            JSON_ERROR_DEPTH            => 'Maximum stack depth exceeded',
            JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH   => 'Underflow or the modes mismatch',
            JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR        => 'Unexpected control character found',
            JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX           => 'Syntax error, malformed JSON',
            JSON_ERROR_UTF8             => 'Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded'
        );
        $error = json_last_error();
        return array_key_exists($error, $errors) ? $errors[$error] : "Unknown error ({$error})";
    }
}
```

Comment: The message in PHP 5.5 is just "`Syntax error`" and I doubt there is malformed JSON. It's just that it ain't JSON then. Just saying.

Comment: With a PHP 5.5 version? Most likely not. The person who wrote the note on PHP.net didn't properly copy the strings to make that replacement actually compatible: http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/ext/json/json.c#845 - But again, just saying. (Just a note on good style: If you quote such a function, give note of the source and link it, too. This can help a lot)

Comment: @hakre Nope; PHP 5.4.7. It is because I use the compatibility function. `json_last_error_msg()` is only available in PHP >=5.5.0. "`Syntax error`" is the same as "`malformed JSON`", though -- it is just a different wording. And you are right; I added a source for the function.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it wasn't stray commas as the answerers suggested, [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) reported BOM artifacts from UTF-8, I'm assuming from copying and pasting.

Once I ran it through and removed the BOM artifacts it decoded properly.

Thanks to all for your help and suggestions.